# MS Access ignores trailing space(s) in primary key validation

Tags: ms-access, primary-key, space, trim

I have an Access table with a TEXT primary key. If I use an INSERT statement to add a row where the primary key value is

`'PART'`

and then try to INSERT another row where the primary key is

`'PART '`

(note the trailing space) then I get

> Microsoft Access ... didn't add 1 record(s) to the table due to key violations

If there is no primary key on the field all is fine, and the second row is indeed added with the trailing space in the field value. But if primary key is set on the field then it causes problems with the key violation error.

How can I avoid this issue?

Comment: If you're typing values into a Form or Datasheet view, try typing `"PART "` instead of just `PART `.

Comment: I'm just trying to INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES ('PART ', 'SOMETHING') and ACCESS inserts 'PART' instead 'PART '.

Comment: How are you verifying that the trailing space is/isn't there? In the Access Query Designer I just did `INSERT INTO Table1 (txt) VALUES ('PART ')` and then when I do `SELECT LEN(txt) AS foo FROM Table1` I get `5`.

Comment: I insert „PART” and then trying insert „PART ”. Inserting „PART ” violates the primary key.

Comment: If there is no primary key on the field all is fine. But if primary key is set on the field then it causes problems with cutting of spaces.

Comment: Why would you want two keys in the table which differ only by trailing spaces? This seems like very bad practice.

Comment: The problem is that i do need to import data from different database and need to keep all lines.

Comment: The behavior you want is characteristic of the SQL datatype `char(n)`. Older versions of Access supported `char(n)` as part of a `create table` statement, but not through the Access GUI. So you might try creating a table using a SQL statement.

Answer (score 1):

Funky behavior. It is normal that Access removes trailing spaces when entering data into a textbox or datasheet field. But that `'PART'` and `'PART '` cannot coexist in a primary key column is weird.

@Gord Thompson: You can first insert 'PART ', that works and the trailing space is saved. But then you cannot insert 'PART'.

If this is the only occurrence of spaces in your data, you could replace the spaces by `Chr(160)`, which also looks like a space, and doesn't violate the PK.

```
CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO tblTextPK (TextPK) VALUES('part')", dbFailOnError
CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO tblTextPK (TextPK) VALUES('part" & Chr(160) & "')", dbFailOnError
```

[image: Table with 2xpart]

In your import code you would use `Replace([Fieldname], " ", Chr(160))`.

(Note that to type `Chr(160)`, you use Alt+255 )

Comment: Good workaround, although the No-Break Space characters *could* cause confusion later on. Another variation would be to only replace the last trailing space with an underscore, so `'X'` would be `'X'`, `'X '` would be `'X_'`, and `'X  '` would be `'X _'`. (Assuming that there weren't already values with trailing underscores, too.) That would let us readily see just where the altered values are.

Answer (score 0):

You could add an additional field, DatebaseID, and fill this during import with A, B, C, etc. 
Then create a *compound* primary key of this field and your current ID.

That would also allow you to get rid of the trailing space(s) which, in general, is a very bad idea.

Comment: Compound key won't work, I have checked. For now i will just add additional text at the end of imported field so the space will go inbetween characters and won't be cutted out.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple :
suppose that your field is : BEN SALEM
so you have to write your commande as below (example Update query) :
"update datatablename set [BEN"+" "+"SALEM]='"+textbox1.text+"' where [ID]='"+textbox2.text+"'";